# Suplemento Excel não Instala

Tags: c#, visual-studio, office-2013

Eu tenho um `Add-In`que usa `.Net Framework 4.0` e `Visual Studio`.
Ele está funcionando bem com o Office 2013. Apos a instalação do Office 2016 , quando eu tento instalar o mesmo `VSTO add-in` é Dando-me um erro da seguinte forma:

> A seguinte solução não pode ser carregada porque a estrutura .net 4.5
>   não está instalada" (para obter mais informações, consulte
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=247460)

Mas eu tenho `.net estrutura 3.5` , `4` e `4.5` instalado nas máquinas.

Já tentei usar o `Fix Microsoft NETFramework repair tool`, mas mesmo assim continua dizendo que não consegue instalar.

Comment: Eu gostaria colocar uma recompensa nesta pergunta, mas ela ainda não tem um dia completo. Alguém me lembre de voltar aqui daqui a três horas.